# BSONTypeError: Decimal128 must take a Buffer or string after updating mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, package.json

This error is the bane of my existence. It defies all my efforts to understand what is going on and fills me with terror so deep that it is melting away my self-image as a semi-competent person.

> BSONTypeError: Decimal128 must take a Buffer or string

The error points to the last line of the following code, which was working just fine until I updated `mongoose` from version `5.10.13` to version `6.0.0`.

```
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { GetReceiptDto, LocationDTO, GetBasketItemDto, GetReceiptExtensionDto, GetReceiptCustomerDto } from './my-module-path';



const inputObject = {
  provider: new ObjectId("64a55b9b0fded53991b4b0d3"),
  currency: 'EUR',
  nfcId: '345676548654567843456',
  customer: null,
  status: 'open',
  serialNo: 'e2e-device-serial-number',
  insufficientFunds: false,
  receiptCounterForStation: 34,
  stationId: 20000,
  timestamp: new Date("2019-09-25T13:38:18.818Z"),
  extensions: {
    cashControl: {
      company: 234,
      department: 345,
      priceList: 567,
      submissionLevel: 678,
      endSaldo: 456,
      cardCounter: 123,
      weight: 789
    },
    _id: new ObjectId("64a55ba40fded53991b4b819")
  }
  _id: new ObjectId("64a55ba40fded53991b4b818"),
  __v: 0,
  sum: new Decimal128("935.7666")
};

const result = plainToClass(GetReceiptDto, inputObject);

console.log(result);
```

I do not understand, since there are no conversions to `Decimal128`.

The `GetReceiptDto` looks like this:

```
export class GetReceiptDto {
    @ApiProperty({
        example: '5cf7a3b1bdaab92c5cf40e0f',
        description: 'Unique identification number for transaction',
    })
    @Expose()
    @TransformMongoId()
    id: string;

    @ApiProperty({
        example: '5cf7a3b1bdaab92c5cf40e0f',
        description: 'Unique identification number for the canceling receipt',
    })
    @Expose()
    @TransformMongoId('cancellationId')
    cancellationId: string;


    @ApiProperty({
        example: '5cf7a3b1bdaab92c5cf40e0f',
        description: 'Unique identification number for provider',
        type: String,
    })
    @Expose()
    @TransformMongoId('provider')
    provider: string;

    @ApiProperty({ example: 'SKU1', description: 'Device serialNo' })
    @Expose()
    serialNo: string;

    @ApiProperty({ example: '447232214880', description: 'NFC ID' })
    @Expose()
    nfcId: string;

    @ApiProperty({
        example: 'EUR',
        description: 'Currency of items price',
    })
    @Expose()
    currency: string;

    @Expose()
    stationId: number;

    @Expose()
    receiptCounterForStation: number;

    @Expose()
    inventoryId: string;

    @ApiProperty({
        example: 230.99,
        description: 'basket items sum',
    })
    @Expose()
    @TransformDecimal128('sum')
    sum: number ;

    @ApiProperty({ description: 'Tells you if receipt created/cancelled a debt. False - regular, True - created/cancelled the debt', type: Boolean })
    @Expose()
    insufficientFunds: boolean;

    @ApiProperty({
        example: 'open',
        description: 'Transaction status',
    })
    @Expose()
    status: TransactionStatus;

    @ApiProperty({ example: '2019-09-25T13:38:18.818Z', description: 'Transaction timestamp in ISO 8601 format' })
    @Expose()
    @Type(() => Date)
    timestamp: Date;

    @ApiProperty({
        type: GetBasketItemDto,
        isArray: true,
        description: 'Transaction basket items',
    })
    @Expose()
    @Type(() => GetBasketItemDto)
    basket: GetBasketItemDto[];

    @ApiProperty({
        type: GetReceiptExtensionDto,
        description: 'Transaction basket items',
    })
    @Expose()
    @Type(() => GetReceiptExtensionDto)
    extensions: GetReceiptExtensionDto;

    @Expose()
    @Type(() => GetReceiptCustomerDto)
    customer: GetReceiptCustomerDto
}
```

and here is the code of the `TransformDecimal128` decorator:

```
export const TransformDecimal128 = (property = 'sum') => {
console.log("avant transforme............ ");
console.log(property);
return Transform(({ value, obj }) => {
    const decimalValue = value && value.toString();
    return decimalValue ? parseFloat(decimalValue) : undefined;
  }, { toClassOnly: true });
};
```

I am at the end of my rope - any help is kindly welcomed.